# Firefox HTML <video /> autoplay doesn't work on Blobs

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, blob, autoplay

I have a bunch of videos with `autoplay`, `playsInline`, `preload='metadata'`, and `muted` attributes. Each video receives its `src` from a Blob created like so:

```
const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], {type: `video/${videoUrl.split('.').pop()}`})
const src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

The videos are all automatically playing on almost all tested browsers / devices, including iOS Safari and Edge. But Firefox refuses. What's weirder is that when I skip the Blob creation process and simply assign each video `src` to its original URL (the one I'm creating the Blobs from e.g `https://website.com/video.mp4`), autoplay works fine in Firefox.

Also, when using the Blob URLs, calling `video.play()` after the videos are ready seems to work on Firefox, but inconsistently on iOS (even when checking `if (video.paused) {video.play()}`, so I'd like to avoid the extra `play` call if possible. Anyone else seeing this??

Comment: Can repro, might warrant a bug report even though it might also be by-design. However, I don't quite understand why you want to avoid the `play` call? Interestingly, they do accept autoplaying dataURIs, but don't do it.

Comment: Glad you're seeing this too! I'm trying to avoid the `play` call because I'm finding it to cause erratic behavior on iOS (i.e random pausing) unless I remove autoplay altogether and manually `play` the vids, and I'm seeing [admittedly unbenchmarked but] better performance if I just let the browsers handle autoplaying at their leisure. TL;DR it seems like a pretty major change to accommodate one strange behavior in Firefox, but of course we must accommodate FF hence my pickle :/

Comment: I opened an issue on mozilla's bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1462967